# dateutil conflict with django

Tags: python, django, pandas, python-dateutil

Here is the question: an error occurs when I import pandas:

```
dateutil: No module named 'dateutil'
```

So i installed dateutil, which is successfully installed, with pip:

```
pip3 install python-dateutil
```

but when i run my django project i got error like this:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 573, in url_patterns
iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 580, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'django_project.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 272, in run
get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/murphy/django_project/django_project/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    from app1.views import IndexView, GLCView
  File "/home/murphy/django_project/apps/app1/views.py", line 15, in <module>
    import myvariant
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/myvariant/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from biothings_client import get_client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/biothings_client/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .base import (BiothingClient, __version__, alwayslist, caching_avail,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/biothings_client/base.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pandas.core.arrays.integer import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .array_ import array  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/array_.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.common import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/dtypes.py", line 53, in <module>
    class Registry:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/dtypes.py", line 84, in Registry
    self, dtype: Union[Type[ExtensionDtype], str]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 1077, in __subclasscheck__
    if super().__subclasscheck__(cls):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/abc.py", line 225, in __subclasscheck__
    for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

There are 2 line relating to my project, which use a biological packages, I don't know if that's the reason.
To continue my django project, i have to uninstall dateutil as a temporary solution.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that your urls.py is properly configured?
Merry Christmas btw.. :)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. This django project has been run for a long time. Recently I want to use pandas on the same server, and get this error.

Comment: can you share the view file where you are getting this error?

Comment: `import myvariant` <br/> `mv = myvariant.MyVariantInfo()` <br/> mv_info = mv.getvariant('chr7:g.140453134T>C')

Comment: Was that the issue?

Comment: My view is above your comment, the error only trace to `import myvariant`, and in my view there are 2 lines use this package.

Comment: I am not able to see the view file :( 
If there is some issue with this package, try reinstalling it in your virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved. It turns out I did not describe what the real problem is, it's pandas(0.25.3) conflict with django(2.2) instead of dateutil. I reinstalled a old version of pandas(0.24.1) and it can work. I don't know why, but it works. Hope this can give other people a hint when they have the same question.